# Why reading pull request data using github cli api causes "gh: Not Found (HTTP 404)" error when run from git-bash terminal?

Tags: bash, git, github-api, git-bash

When using the [github cli api](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/pulls#get-a-pull-request) to read pull request data through git-bash terminal I get "gh: Not Found (HTTP 404)" error.
When I run the exact same script via PowerShell terminal or via wsl it works great.
Any idea why this is happening?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While the [gh code sample in the REST API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/pulls#get-a-pull-request=) does have an extra `/` prefix, the actual [gh api man page](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_api) does not:

Examples:

```bash
# list releases in the current repository
$ gh api repos/{owner}/{repo}/releases

# post an issue comment
$ gh api repos/{owner}/{repo}/issues/123/comments -f body='Hi from CLI'
```

> Placeholder values "`{owner}`", "`{repo}`", and "`{branch}`" in the endpoint argument will get replaced with values from the repository of the current directory or the repository specified in the `GH_REPO` environment variable.
>
> Note that in some shells, for example PowerShell, you may need to enclose any value that contains "`{...}`" in quotes to prevent the shell from applying special meaning to curly braces.

Answer (score 2):

I decided to answer my own question because it took me several hours to realize the solution to this and I couldn't find it anywhere online.
Basically, the reason this happens is purely due to the way the path is written.
If you remove the `/` from before the word 'repos' then the command works perfectly well both on PowerShell, wsl and git-bash terminals.

So the correct script should be:

```
# GitHub CLI api
# https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_api

gh api \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  repos/OWNER/REPO/pulls/PULL_NUMBER
```

Again, this is different than what is officially written in the GitHub API documentation because I removed the `/` before the word 'repos'.
I hope this helps others as well.

Answer (score 1):

I also got the similar error but not because of the reason mentioned above. The reason was there were trailing spaces after `gh api \`. After I removed those trailing spaces, got the response I was expecting.

```
gh api \ <check spaces here, there should not be any>
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  repos/OWNER/REPO/pulls/PULL_NUMBER
```